# Bootstrap with collapsable nav - what I get doesn't match the docs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <style>
            div[class^='span'] {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="brand" href="#">Bootstrap Test</a>

                    <ul class="nav pull-right nav-collapse collapse">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="containter-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">2</div>
                <div class="span10">10</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following:

[image: Bootstrap collapsed nav]

Yet, in the [example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar) on the Bootstrap site, all of its collapsed links form a vertical list.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Taking `.pull-right` out of the nav `<ul>` and replacing it with `<div class="span8">` solved some of it.  Unfortunately, it looks like my `.brand` element is causing some issues.

If I shrink my browser to the point where the collapsable nav button is next to my `.brand`, the links below don't form a list:

[image]

If I shrink the browser so the links form a list, then the button pops below the `.brand`:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the button on the same line as the `.brand` *and* force the links below to form a vertical list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, you are missing a very important piece of code in there.

You need to link `bootstrap-responsive.css` or `bootstrap-responsive.min.css`

Additionally, this is what your menu should look like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>

            <a class="brand" href="#">Bootstrap Test</a>

            <div class="pull-right nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes no difference for me.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? Just by adding the responsive css to your code, I got an almost working header. Only problem is that you dont have a `<div class="nav-collapse collapse">` before that `<ul class="nav">` (which is all it should be)

Comment: Added the code for your menu on the main answer. Changing that and adding the responsive css should fix your problem.

Comment: Putting the `nav` list in that container div did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must be using `inline-block` or `float:left`. 
 
If so then remove `float` and use `display:block`

Comment: The problem seems to be the `.pull-right` I put on my nav list.

Comment: Edited my question because of a new, related wrinkle that popped up.

Comment: @KevinM1 All the stuff that you want to fix are in `bootstrap.min.css`.. Only thing is you have to find the correct one and change.. they will be at extreme bottom i.e `@media screen (max-width:400px)` or so